# angularjs get paramater from url

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i'm currently working on a asp.net mvc site in which we are using angularjs for model binding.  i have a controller setup but i need to grab the id from the url to pass it to the service.  my url looks like:

```
http://localhost/myapp/section/5
```

I need to grab the 5 out of the url, we are not using angular for routing, is there anyway to grab that through angular?  Otherwise i could use .net to inject that into a global js variable and use angular to read the id from there.

I setup my angular controller as below:

```
    myModule.controller('SectionController', ['$scope', 'sectionRepository', '$routeParams', SectionController]);

function SectionController($scope, sectionRepository, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;

    alert($routeParams.id);
```

the alert returns 'undefined', I'm assuming because I never setup the routes in angular, is there a way to do it without the setup of routes, as we don't want to use angular for routing.

Comment: maybe using $location.absUrl() and parsing the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$location` service to grab the URL.  From there, just parse it.

```
function SectionController($location) {
    var url = $location.url();
    //regex is slow, you should use substring/slice instead
    //var regex = /(?:section\/)[0-9]+/;

    var id = url.substring(url.indexOf("section/") + "section/".length);
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: are you sure $location.url() will work if angular is not routing the application?

Comment: @SergioMarron According to the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), it does not depend on routing.  Changes in `window.location` are live and `$location` can see them.

Comment: I tried $location.path() and it returned an empty string. window.location.pathname worked.

Comment: @SergioMarron for me $location.url() did not work either, but after looking through the debugger, I saw there was is $location.absUrl() which worked.